# My string comparison doesn't work with hidden ascii characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to compare the concatenation of two strings like this:

```
SELECT TestChemicalName, ResultChemicalName,
CASE 
    WHEN LAB_TestChemicalName + LAB_ResultChemicalName = TestChemicalName + ResultChemicalName THEN NULL 
    WHEN LAB_TestChemicalName + LAB_ResultChemicalName <> TestChemicalName + ResultChemicalName THEN LAB_TestChemicalName + ' ' + LAB_ResultChemicalName
    ELSE NULL
END AS FinalElementName
FROM dbo.chemicalTraceTesting
```

If `LAB_TestChemicalName + LAB_ResultChemicalName` is the same/equals `TestChemicalName + ResultChemicalName`, then I want to return `NULL`.

However, if they are not equal, I want to return it as `LAB_TestChemicalName + ' ' + LAB_ResultChemicalName`

90% of the time this works, but if there are hidden ascii encoding symbols, like if someone just did a copy and paste from HTML, or Word or Excel, it will sometimes have strange characters. Then my query above won't catch that.

Is there a better way to compare two strings?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem here isn't the comparison, it's the data. It seems you need to be doing *something* to ensure the data in your database is "clean".

Comment: Though your `CASE` could be much succinct as `CASE WHEN {Not equal to Comparison} THEN LAB_TestChemicalName + ' ' + LAB_ResultChemicalName END`. There's no need for the equality check or the `ELSE NULL`; provided the (not equal to) expression isn't true, the `CASE` will return `NULL` by default.

Comment: Agree with Larnu, dirty data appears to be the issue here, and this is assuming this is a `VARCHAR` and not a `TEXT` data type. I'm curious, can you provide an example of the string that doesn't work? I'm wondering if you can alleviate your problem with a simple `LTRIM` AND `RTRIM`, or if your roadblock is an actual character that must be dealt with. If there is some kind of consistency, you could account for it with another `CASE` and a `SUBSTRING`, but I'm guessing you didn't get that lucky?

Comment: @Larnu thank you, I have no access to database except through `SELECT` queries.  DBA is overseas.  I was just hoping for a way to account for hidden characters when doing a comparison.  thank you.

Comment: @jw11432 thank you, I will try the `LTRIM` method.

Comment: [LTRIM()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql), [RTRIM()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql) and [TRIM()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) only deal with space characters, `CHAR(32)`. If you have other control characters in the text, such as tabs (`CHAR(9)`), carriage returns (`CHAR(13)`) or linefeeds (`CHAR(10)`) you'll need to deal with those separately. If you suspect that a particular value has hidden characters you can reveal them with `SELECT CAST(someValue AS VARBINARY(MAX))`

Comment: This is also a good use for **NULLIF()**:  `SELECT NULLIF(LAB_TestChemicalName + ' ' + LAB_ResultChemicalName, TestChemicalName + ' ' + ResultChemicalName)`

Answer (score 1):

With bad data you're never going to get a reliable solution. The best you can do is some heursitic that is good enough most of the time.

What you need to do is compute a *hash* of the string that has the property that if two strings have the same hash then you consider them to be equal.

Maybe something like.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Slap(@source nvarchar(max)) RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @hash varchar(max)
    ;
    WITH cteC AS (
        SELECT 0 AS I, SUBSTRING(@source, 0, 1) AS C
        UNION ALL
        SELECT I + 1, SUBSTRING(@Source, I, 1) AS c FROM cteC WHERE I <= LEN(@source)
    )
    SELECT @hash = STRING_AGG(C, '')
    FROM cteC
    WHERE ASCII(C) >= 32
        AND ASCII(C) <= 126

    RETURN @hash
END
```

This is likely to be very slow.
And it'll fail on long strings.